# Resource controller returns not found exception on show

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I have a route as follows:

```
Route::resource('/admin/products/', 'ProductsController');
```

So if I go to `myapp.app:8000/admin/products/` I get all the products:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return View::make('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

But if I go to `myapp.app:8000/admin/products/1` where I have the following:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return "Hi!";
}
```

I get an error page: **NotFoundHttpException**. Have I done something wrong?

In case it helps, I have attached my `php artisan routes` output for the relevant queries:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                             | Name                    | Action                                      | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD admin/users/{month?}   |                         | AdminController@users                   | admin          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products         | admin.products..index   | ProductsController@index                | admin          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/create  | admin.products..create  | ProductsController@create               | admin          |               |
|        | POST admin/products             | admin.products..store   | ProductsController@store                | admin          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/{}      | admin.products..show    | ProductsController@show                 | admin          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/{}/edit | admin.products..edit    | ProductsController@edit                 
|        | PUT admin/products/{}           | admin.products..update  | ProductsController@update               | admin          |               |
|        | PATCH admin/products/{}         |                         | ProductsController@update               | admin          |               |
|        | DELETE admin/products/{}        | admin.products..destroy | ProductsController@destroy              | admin          |               |
```

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpautoload` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has to do with how Laravel parses the route. Change your route to:

```
Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProductsController');
```

And the list of outputs from Artisan should change to something like this:

```
GET|HEAD admin/products/{products}
```